# rails - reject_if - only reject if it is not the only item in the collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In other words the project must have at least one valid task.  So can not be rejected if it is the only task in the collection of project -> tasks.

In other other words if there is already one task in the project, tasks with all blank fields should be rejected.

```
Project 
  has_many :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks
Task 
  belongs_to :project
```

edit:
blank tasks should be rejected, however there must be at least one task in a project for the project to be valid.  If three blank tasks are in the params hash only 2 of them can be rejected.  The first task must attempt (and fail) validation.

Is there railsy way of doing this?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. I'm having a hard time understanding what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry.  I added more.  Thanks!

Comment: So you want the two "extra" blank tasks to get rejected before validation? In other words, if I try to submit a Project with 10 blank tasks, rather than it coming back and saying "Taks 1 can't be blank", "Task 2 can't be blank", "Task 3 can't be blank", etc.. You want it to just get rid of tasks 2-10 and say "Task 1 can't be blank?" I think if you get 10 tasks, you should try to validate all of them. The user decided to send that number for a reason, even if they're not valid. I wouldn't expect them to just get thrown away.

Comment: But if you do want to actually do it the way you're saying, why not just go through all the tasks submitted and remove them if they're blank, unless it's the last task left in the set. Then only !blank tasks or a single blank tasks make it to validation. Doing all that in before_validation would be the rails-y way.

Comment: Are you using accepts_nested_attributes?

Comment: If they enter all blank tasks the project isn't valid so it has to squawk about that.   If they enter information for 10 tasks they all get accepted then validated (and errors displayed accordingly).  I don't want it to come back saying "name can't be blank" for all 10 tasks if they only intended to create one.

Comment: Yes, accepts nested attributes (op updated)